# Inheritance problems with EntityFrameworkCore Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

I recently decided to implement the ASP.NET Identity functionality, on a website I'm developing in ASP.NET Core MVC.

Let's take a quick look at the tables and classes in topic:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public stirng LastName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ISO { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*The `Country` class is somewhat irrelevant, but in case you wanted the reference from the `User` class.*

With this setup, I've configured my database context like this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<IdentityUser>.ToTable("User");
        builder.Entity<IndentityRole>.ToTable("Roles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>.ToTable("UserRoles");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>.ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>.ToTable("UserLogins");
    }
}
```

I'm using custom tables (renamed) and mapping them like this.

**Problem**

Now, whenever I run my project, at the first database call I'm making, I'm getting the following error:

> The entity type 'User' should derive from 'IdentityUser' to reflect the hierarchy of the corresponding CLR types.

To me, this error says that my class `User` doesn't inherit from the interface `IdentityUser`, and I'm not quite sure why that is so? Clearly my class `User` DOES inherit from `IdentityUser`?

Comment: What does your User class look like?

Comment: I already posted that

Comment: I guess you'll have to add another entity of type IdentityUser because otherwise EF won't be able to store User's in the database - it stores each class on the hierarchy separately.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: Are you using a database-first approach?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Should you not be doing `builder.Entity<User>.ToTable("User");`  instead? And if you do DB-first, does `User` table contain all the fields for `IdentityUser`?

Comment: @trailmax How did I not see that! Thank you, that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUser>.ToTable("User");
```

You need to put

```
builder.Entity<User>.ToTable("Users");
```

And in the Startup class where you add the identity service you need to do this

```
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>();
```

Comment: Any measurements you need to take after changing it?